# I am asked to convert a phone number in words into a number and return as a string

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class temp{
public static void main(String args[]){
    String phone_string="one double two triple four";
    String[] arr=phone_string.split(" ",0);
    int freq=1;
    String res="";
    HashMap<String,Character> hm1=new HashMap<>();
    hm1.put("zero",'0');
    hm1.put("one",'1');
    hm1.put("two",'2');
    hm1.put("three",'3');
    hm1.put("four",'4');
    hm1.put("five",'5');
    hm1.put("six",'6');
    hm1.put("seven",'7');
    hm1.put("eight",'8');
    hm1.put("nine",'9');
    HashMap<String,Integer> hm2=new HashMap<>();
    hm2.put("double",2);
    hm2.put("triple",3);
    for(String str:arr){
        if(hm2.containsKey(str)){
            freq*=hm2.get(str);
        }else{
            res+=(freq*hm1.get(str));
            freq=1;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println(res);
}
}
```

Don't know why this is not working it gives me output as - 49100156
For ex - string="one double two triple four", output="122444"
Is it giving me a garbage value??
What are the corrections??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: You are using _char_ values for _hm1_ and _int_ values for _hm2_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are multiplying `freq` by your *character*, which creates a garbage number, and then adding that garbage number to your String one time:

```
res+=(freq*hm1.get(str));
```

You need to add the character to your String `freq` times, so you need a loop:

```
char c = hm1.get(str);
for (int i=0; i<freq; i++) {
    res += c;
}
```

Or if you're using Java 11 or later, there is convenience method for String to repeat it:

```
res += String.valueOf(hm1.get(str)).repeat(freq);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line: `res+=(freq*hm1.get(str));`. It is multiplying the frequency with the ASCII value of the character, not repeating the character `freq` times. This would work in Python but not in Java. You should change this line to repeat the character `freq` times. Below is example fix to your code:

```
for(String str:arr){
    if(hm2.containsKey(str)){
        freq=hm2.get(str);
    }else{
        for(int i=0;i<freq;i++){
            res+=hm1.get(str);
        }
        freq=1;
    }
}
```

This will give you the expected output "122444" for the input "one double two triple four".

I would also suggest you use StringBuilder instead of String for res variable. It would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The *char* values *1, 2, 3,* etc., are not equivalent to their integer values.

Here is an example.

```java
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
String ss = "one double two triple four";
int i = 1;
for (String e : ss.split(" ")) {
    if (e.equals("double")) i = 2;
    else if (e.equals("triple")) i = 3;
    else {
        s.append(
            (switch (e) {
                case "zero" -> "0";
                case "one" -> "1";
                case "two" -> "2";
                case "three" -> "3";
                case "four" -> "4";
                case "five" -> "5";
                case "six" -> "6";
                case "seven" -> "7";
                case "eight" -> "8";
                case "nine" -> "9";
                default -> "";
            }).repeat(i));
        i = 1;
    }
}
```